# Which MySQL Collation to use so that queries match the word exactly and not its accents?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I have a column which has values like 'fur' and 'für'.
Now if I write the query

```
select * from table where text = 'fur';
```

it gives me both 'fur' and 'für' and I want it to only return 'fur'.
Which charset and collation should I use?
Also when I try to use a unique index it doesn't allow me to insert 'für' as it matches with the already inserted 'fur'.

Comment: Use a `COLLATION` with a name ending in `_bin` (to compare the bits without any handling of case or accent) or containing `_as_` (for "accent sensitive").  Use `SHOW COLLATION;` to see what collations are available on the version you are using.